# Getting an overflow:auto element to auto scroll

Tags: css, overflow

I have a big div with text inside:

```
#big-div {
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

How can I make it so that when new content is added to the div (and an overflow occurs), the div automatically scrolls to the bottom. In other words, the newest added content is always visible. The same behaviour that terminal emulators have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to force it using JavaScript.

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("big-div");
myDiv.scrollTop = myDiv.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: do you have any demo for this?